# How to share content of a webpage to facebook page of the site itself

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I red the facebook api, graph api, app id/secret id, access token things. I have downloaded the php sdk from git.

I am able to publish a message from graph api explorer by getting an access token from me/accounts for spesific facebook page where I am admin. But I cant find how to do that within my web site. I want to do it with php.

I knwo here is not the area to ask a question like taht, but I couldnt find a solution or way to do it. I have nothing to do with any specific user. The content will be shared between the web site and the facebook page releated wtih that site.